# How to assign inconstant value to reg in Task , In Verilog?

Tags: initialization, task, verilog, assign

I have faced this Error. Although I seek whole the net, I did not find good answer.

I want to assign a conditional value to a reg in a Task.
The Error is this :

> ## Error: VCP2648 Control_Unit_Tasks.v : (60, 50): Reg initializer must be a constant: DR==10'b0000000000?1'b1:1'b0";

And My written code for a Task which arises this error is this:

```
task Registers_Inc_Generator(output PC_inc,DR_inc,AC_inc, input [7:0]D,T, input[5:0]B, input[9:0] AC,DR, input R,Z);
reg isDR_Zero=(DR==10'b0000000000)?1'b1:1'b0;
reg isAC_Zero=(AC==10'b0000000000)?1'b1:1'b0;
endtask
```

I will appreciate if anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can also avoid the ternary operator while initializing. You could do something like -


isDR_Zero = DR == 10'h0;              
isAC_Zero = AC == 10'h0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite self-explanatory. When you have

```
reg isDR_Zero=(DR==10'b0000000000)?1'b1:1'b0;
```

you are initialising a variable. You can only initialise a variable to a constant value. Instead you must *declare* the variables first and then *assign* to them:

```
  task Registers_Inc_Generator(output PC_inc,DR_inc,AC_inc, input [7:0]D,T, input[5:0]B, input[9:0] AC,DR, input R,Z);
    begin
      reg isDR_Zero;
      reg isAC_Zero;
      isDR_Zero=(DR==10'b0000000000)?1'b1:1'b0;
      isAC_Zero=(AC==10'b0000000000)?1'b1:1'b0;
    end
  endtask
```